# How do test frameworks stop execution of running tests?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, task, test-framework

I'm implementing my own test framework in .NET and ran into a problem with how to correctly stop execution of a running test. The test method being executed is obviously not cooperating so I can't use CancellationTokenSource and Thread.Abort() is deprecated. How do existing test frameworks like NUnit handle this?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick perusal of source code, it seems that `Thread.Abort()` is the mechanism of choice.  This makes sense at first glance since the runner needs to execute arbitrary code and then kill it immediately.

Looking at NUnit's source (v3), when a timeout value is specified it forces the test [onto a separate thread](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/a40d45e7909b9409e94cecfe2a8dfe883efbb8b0/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/Execution/WorkItem.cs#L267).  Then, if the test exceeds its timeout value, it [is killed](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/a40d45e7909b9409e94cecfe2a8dfe883efbb8b0/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/Execution/WorkItem.cs#L317) via a call to [`Thread.Abort()`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/a40d45e7909b9409e94cecfe2a8dfe883efbb8b0/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/ThreadUtility.cs#L62).

Similarly for MbUnit (v3), it runs the test on a [separate thread using a sandbox](https://github.com/Gallio/mbunit-v3/blob/c593986049d52624cde5d1812047466f2a775ffe/src/Gallio/Gallio/Framework/Pattern/PatternTestExecutor.cs#L201) that creates a [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://github.com/Gallio/mbunit-v3/blob/c593986049d52624cde5d1812047466f2a775ffe/src/Gallio/Gallio/Framework/Sandbox.cs#L280).  When that timer expires, it invokes [`Abort()` on the sandbox](https://github.com/Gallio/mbunit-v3/blob/c593986049d52624cde5d1812047466f2a775ffe/src/Gallio/Gallio/Framework/Sandbox.cs#L221), which invokes [`Thread.Abort()`](https://github.com/Gallio/mbunit-v3/blob/c593986049d52624cde5d1812047466f2a775ffe/src/Gallio/Gallio/Common/Concurrency/ThreadAbortScope.cs#L228) on the running test.

Also, [according to Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs,526) I do not see `Thread.Abort()` marked as obsolete/deprecated.

Comment: Ok, not deprecated but everywhere you read that it should not be used because it is dangerous and can lead to invalid states, but I guess I have no other options.